About diode question solution
While solving the diode question, a point like this stuck in my head, I did the solution in this way, but I ask you to help the community
For X value; (I thought it should be found with a voltage divider)
X = (2k / 2k+10k) x 9V
X = 1.5Volt
For the B value; (I thought it would be done using a non-inverting tip)
B = (1 + 2K/2K) x 1.5V
B = 3Volt
Is this the right solution? I'm in the learning phase, I want to be sure.


Yes, that looks good to me, on both parts.
There is nominally no current through R7, so it has no effect on the voltage divider. So why is it there? In real opamps, there is an input bias current. If the resistances connected to the two inputs are different, it creates an additional offset error at the output. Somebody looked at R8 and R4 and decided that R7 should have the same value.
This is actually wrong on two counts:

The parallel combination of R8 and R4 is actually only 1 kΩ
The source impedance of R1 and R2 is already close to 2 kΩ

Therefore, R7 is actually unnecessary, and R4 and R8 should be increased to 4 kΩ each.
